# Decorating a model class in django issuing save in the decorator

Tags: python, django, django-models, decorator

I have several models that save log data to my database. I also have a "recent events" app and I would like to choose which models send data to the events app. I thought a decorator would be good for this, so I could just add it to the models I want:

```
@logger
class TemperatureLog(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Device = models.ForeignKey(TemperatureDevice)
    Data = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Here is the events model, Im using generic foreign keys:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    Active = models.BooleanField()
    Queue = models.BooleanField()
    ContentType = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    ObjectID = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Event = generic.GenericForeignKey('ContentType', 'ObjectID')
```

And here is the decorator:

```
def logger(event):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        from toolbox.event.models import Event
        event(*args, **kwargs).save()
        myid = event(*args, **kwargs).id
        new = Event(Event=event.objects.get(id=myid))

        if Event.objects.all().filter(Active=True).count() >= 25:
            new.Queue = True
            new.save()

        else:
            new.Active = True
            new.save()

            for item in Event.objects.all().filter(Queue=True):
                item.Queue = False
                item.Active = True
                item.save()

                if  Event.objects.all().filter(Active=True).count() >= 25:
                    break
        return event(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

It works as it should, it creates the event instance and saves it. The problem that I have  is that save() would be called twice. One in the decorator and the second in the actual code that collects the temperature logs (since I wont know ahead of time which apps will send events and which wont or if they might change in the future). So I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this. I like the decorator approach since all I have to do is add it to the model class, but I am not very convinced of having save being called twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using post_save signal for all models

```py
def log_saved_event(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    # handle Event class
    pass

from django.db.models import signals
from django.db import models

for m in models.get_models():
    signals.post_save.connect(log_saved_event, sender=m)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "in principle" response to your question is to consider using [the `pre_save` signal built into Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/).

Basically, you connect a listener function to the `pre_save` signal, documented in full at the link above, and you can modify the desired properties on your model instance. Only after your listener finishes executing (as well as any other listeners connected to `pre_save` on that model) will the model instance be saved to the database.

If I understand your code correctly, you want your `Queue` variable set to `True` if and only if there are 25 or more active event records in the database, and `False` otherwise (with the opposite for `Active` -- why you need two booleans I don't understand). You could do that with signals by doing something like this...

```
from django.db.signals import pre_save

def update_event_active_queue_status(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if Event.objects.filter(Active=True).count() >= 25:
        instance.Queue = True
    else:
        instance.Active = True
pre_save.connect(update_event_active_queue_status, sender=Event)
```

A separate problem that you're trying to solve, and I don't think this is the right place for it, is moving queued events back to active when the number of active events falls below 25. I don't know your exact needs, but I'd probably have that done on a cron job or by some other event manager, rather than being addressed here. Right now, if no events are added into the system (or changed in some other way), items would never be pulled out of queue. That's probably not what you want.

Of course, you know your needs better than I do, so take my recommendations with a grain of salt.